# Is there any way to set look in of Control F bar option to values instead of formulas?

Tags: excel, settings, shortcut

I want to fix the setting of Control F bar in excel. after clicking option in ctrl F , I want to set look in to values permanently instead of formula. Is there any way?

Comment: There might be a hack with VBA but no setting as far as I know.

Comment: try [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/find-replace-default-options/4fcfabc2-46fe-4eec-b6cf-749ad3b73144) out if you are ready for some `vba` coding :)